# Custom page template, not acting as page

Tags: customization

I have defined several page templates on my site http://178.21.128.82/. When I set my pages to use one of these page templates, wordpress seems to stop treating it as a page:

- It is not accepted in the is_page() conditional tag
- The body class "page" is not present (instead its showing "home").

Only when I use the default page template for my pages they are truly treated as a page by wordpress.

Anyone got a clue what´s going on?

Thanks!

Added:

```
query_posts('meta_key=wpfp_favorites&orderby=meta_value');

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $start = get_post_meta($post->ID, '5Start', true);
    $stop = get_post_meta($post->ID, '6Slutt', true);

    if(is_active($start, $stop)) { 
        $offer = print_offer($post->ID, $start, $stop);
        echo $offer;
    }

endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Most likely you are messing up main Loop, typical reason is wrong usage of `query_posts()`. Please add code from template that has this issue.

Comment: added some code

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was messing up with query_posts()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought so...

You are using `query_posts()` and this nukes native page's loop and replaces all relevant data with your query. Since your query isn't for page - your page is no longer treated as such.

**Always** use `get_posts()` or new `WP_Query` object for secondary loops.

See [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: can´t wp_reset_query() do the job?

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't matter. It is not meant and should not be used for secondary loops (ever). It makes sense to use right function from the start rather than trying to fix inherently broken approach.

Comment: What do you mean by secondary loops? Any loops outside index.php?

Comment: Any Loop other than what WordPress creates internally for every page (based on requested URL). Even if you are not querying or displaying anything at all there is still main Loop working in background. The purpose of `query_posts()` is to change parameters of that Loop.